# Android Studio - Server Certificate Expired throwing "Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, certificate

I cant able to create new projects.

Android studio throwing "Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

I have checked my server certificate which got expired a week before

Can we able to renew the expired certificate

kindly suggest me

Thanks in advance